# Is there .bat equivalent of shell select?

Tags: windows, shell, select, batch-file, cmd

Hi i basicaly want to know if i can do this in bat cmd windows environment.

```
#!/bin/bash
select var1 in abc ced efg hij
do
echo "Present value of var1 is $var1"
echo $REPLY
done
```

Comment: You should look into PowerShell, which replaces the Windows Command Processor, and is _far_ more powerful.

Comment: I have to use the normal cmd bat

Comment: Look at the `for` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, no.

But you might consider Perl, http://www.perl.org/get.html#win32 which runs happily on Windows and has several modules that act as `select`, for example http://metacpan.org/pod/Shell::POSIX::Select

Comment: Very odd that the OP will accept a non-native Perl solution, but will not consider PowerShell that is native. Nothing wrong, just odd.

Comment: I agree, but no one gave a solution using PowerShell, only a comment.

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be what you're looking for. I have no idea where $REPLY is coming from though.

```
 for %%a in (abc ced efg hij) do echo present value of var1 is %%a
```